# How to put a time and date stamp in a php script for a form?

Tags: php, html

I have a php script which works with my html markup to send the form details to an email address, and also store the form details into a csv file.

This is the code for my php:
**EDIT**

```
<?php
            $subject = $_POST['QSpeed Inquiry - '];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['EMAIL'];
            $comments = $_POST['comments'];
            $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
            $date = date(r);

            $fp = fopen("comments.csv","a");
            $list = array($name,$email,$comments,$date);
            fputcsv($fp, $list);
            rewind($fp);
            fclose($fp);

            $strTo = "email@domain.com";
            $strSubject = "QSpeed inquiry -";
            $strFrom = trim($_POST["QSpeed Inquiry - name"]);
            $str_content = "From". trim($_POST["name"]) . "\r\n" . "Email: " . trim($_POST["EMAIL"]) . "\r\n" . "Comments: " . trim($_POST["comments"]) . "\r\n" ;
            mail($strTo,$strFrom,$strSubject,$str_content); 

            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'></SCRIPT>");
            echo "<script>alert(' Message was sent successfully. Thank you! ')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.history.go(-1)</script>";      

?>
```

I want to add a time and date stamp to the CSV file for the script. How can I get the time and date stamp and have it stored in the CSV file.

Comment: `rewind(); fclose()` is all polite and stuff, but the VHS tape rental days are over... you don't have to rewind a file you're about to close.

Comment: http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/form.php This is my script. It's not working.

Comment: @James `date(1);` is not what you want here. Did you look through the `date()` manual? Replace that line with `date('F m');` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. The subject is not appearing. It appears as NO Subject. I dont know why.

Comment: @James Ah, good call on using `date(r);`. Place subject second rather than third. `mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers )` `$headers` should contain your 'from' value. EDIT: I see what you're saying now, sorry. You've mixed case: `$subject = $_POst['QSpeed Inquiry - '];` Try changing that to POST - variables in PHP are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

What parts exactly are you having trouble with? To get the timestamp, look at [`date][1]`. Store it in a variable, then put it in the `$list` array before the CSV write.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this:

```
$time = date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time());
```

And see if it results in what you wanted. If not, explore the manual and alter the output based on available options for the functions. I have a feeling you'd benefit greatly from reading the documentation on `date()` and `time()`. They may be confusing on the outside, and they can be tricky to use, but this is very basic usage that you can and should understand.

Answer (score -1):

First of all - your $strTo parameter is missing the leading quotes ("me@domain.com")

To get the UNIX Timestamp with php, just use the function time()

So by your syntax you would just need to change

```php
$list = array($name,$email,$comments);
```

To

```php
$list = array($name,$email,$comments, time());
```

Shai.

Comment: There is no `timestamp()` function in PHP - you mean `time()`

Comment: Arrgh, my bad :) Thanks for the heads up.